# Trying to understand XSLT Muenchian Method transformation

Tags: xslt

I came across the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) when looking for a way of grouping elements in an XML file that has been produced by converted a CSV file.

**Source**

```
<file>
    <patient>
        <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1342718.Y</Lab_Specimen_Number>
        <Patient_Number>LOC0000015</Patient_Number>
        <ORG/>
        <Specimen/>
        <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin/>
    </patient>
    <patient>
        <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1342727.V</Lab_Specimen_Number>
        <Patient_Number>LOC0000001</Patient_Number>
        <ORG>Coliform</ORG>
        <Specimen>L,18.1342727.VA</Specimen>
        <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>S</Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>
    </patient>
    <patient>
        <Lab_Specimen_Number/>
        <Patient_Number/>
        <ORG>Staphylococcus aureus</ORG>
        <Specimen>L,18.1342727.VA</Specimen>
        <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>S</Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>
    </patient>
    <patient>
        <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1346290.T</Lab_Specimen_Number>
        <Patient_Number>LOC0000001</Patient_Number>
        <ORG>Coliform</ORG>
        <Specimen>L,18.1346290.TA</Specimen>
        <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>S</Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>
    </patient>
    <patient>
        <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1342713.X</Lab_Specimen_Number>
        <Patient_Number>LOC0000009</Patient_Number>
        <ORG/>
        <Specimen/>
        <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin/>
    </patient>
</file>
```

Based on the article I have changed the match when assigning a key to `patient[Specimen != '']` instead of just `patient` as it is possible for the Specimen value to be blank and these would be missing from the final output if just `patient` was used.

**Transformation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="patients-by-specimen" match="patient[Specimen != '']" use="Specimen" />
  <xsl:template match="file">
    <file>
      <xsl:for-each select="patient[count(. | key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]) = 1]">
        <patient>
          <xsl:copy-of select="Lab_Specimen_Number" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="Patient_Number" />
          <Specimen>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Specimen" />
            <Organisms>
              <xsl:for-each select="key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)">
                <Organism>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="ORG"/>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin"/>
                </Organism>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </Organisms>
          </Specimen>
        </patient>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whilst the transformation above gives me the desired output I don't fully understand how this line is working:

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="patient[count(. | key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]) = 1]">
> ```

Could someone explain this iteration in the context of my source file?

**Output**

```
<file>
  <patient>
    <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1342718.Y</Lab_Specimen_Number>
    <Patient_Number>LOC0000015</Patient_Number>
    <Specimen>
      <Specimen/>
      <Organisms/>
    </Specimen>
  </patient>
  <patient>
    <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1342727.V</Lab_Specimen_Number>
    <Patient_Number>LOC0000001</Patient_Number>
    <Specimen>
      <Specimen>L,18.1342727.VA</Specimen>
      <Organisms>
        <Organism>
          <ORG>Coliform</ORG>
          <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>S</Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>
        </Organism>
        <Organism>
          <ORG>Staphylococcus aureus</ORG>
          <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>S</Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>
        </Organism>
      </Organisms>
    </Specimen>
  </patient>
  <patient>
    <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1346290.T</Lab_Specimen_Number>
    <Patient_Number>LOC0000001</Patient_Number>
    <Specimen>
      <Specimen>L,18.1346290.TA</Specimen>
      <Organisms>
        <Organism>
          <ORG>Coliform</ORG>
          <Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>S</Antibiotic_Amox_Ampicillin>
        </Organism>
      </Organisms>
    </Specimen>
  </patient>
  <patient>
    <Lab_Specimen_Number>L,18.1342713.X</Lab_Specimen_Number>
    <Patient_Number>LOC0000009</Patient_Number>
    <Specimen>
      <Specimen/>
      <Organisms/>
    </Specimen>
  </patient>
</file>
```

Comment: Well, you have cited the article that explain the approach in detail so compare the explanation given there for `contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1]` to `patient[count(. | key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]) = 1]`, it says "There are a couple of generic methods of testing whether two nodes are identical: ... see whether a node set made up of the two nodes has one or two nodes in it - nodes can't be repeated in a node set, so if there's only one node in it, then they must be the same node"

Comment: Yes I read that but I don't follow, an explanation of the iterations would help me understand what is going on

Comment: Do you understand what `<xsl:for-each select="patient">...</xsl:for-each>` does? Would you understand what `<xsl:for-each select="patient[. is key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]]">...</xsl:for-each>` does, assuming `is` is an operator that returns true if the left and right node operand are the identical node? XSLT/XPath 1 does not have such an operator, so you need some other way to express that you only want to select the first `patient` in each group based on the `patients-by-specimen` key. The `count(. | key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]) = 1` is one way doing that.

Comment: I think I now understand. Looking at my source file the first `patient` element is a match, the key lookup returns nothing so there is only 1 node. The second `patient` element is a match as the key lookup returns the same element so there is only 1 node. The third `patient` element is NOT a match as the key lookup returns the previous `patient` element and therefore has 2 nodes etc. Is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn't use the term or word `match` in this context and XSLT as it has a different use for `match` patterns but you are right that for your first `patient` element the node-set `key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)` is empty so `count` of the union of that patient and the empty node-set is `1` and the predicate is true. For the second `patient` the `key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)` returns a node-set of two elements but the `key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]` is the same as that second `patient` so again the predicate is true.

Comment: For the third `patient` then the `count` is two as the `key('patients-by-specimen', Specimen)[1]` returns, as you rightly say, the previous, the second `patient`, so the predicate is false.